# JDBC MySQL connection using Unix Socket

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, unix, jdbc

I am using MySQL using the *--skip-networking* option on Linux.

Trying to connect my J2EE based application (using servlets) to the MySQL database using JDBC.

When was using MySQL with the *--skip-networking* option **disabled**, I was connecting to the database as:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase","myuser","mypassword");
```

After having enabled the *--skip-networking* option, I am trying to connect it as:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase","myuser","mypassword");
```

But this does not seem to work, and I get **java.lang.NullPointerException** when I try to connect to the database in my application.

After commenting out the *--skip-networking* option and using the old JDBC statement, I can connect to the database.

*Note* - I am able to connect to the database via the command line mysql client with the *--skip-networking* option enabled.

Can anyone tell me how to connect to the database **from JDBC**? I tried searching for it but could not any satisfactory answer that worked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Java >= 7

Comment: Yes java 7.u65_2.5.2-1

Comment: Can you post full stacktrace bcoz i am on linux and tried to connect to mysql using JDBC and it works fine

Comment: Can you give a link on how to post a stacktrace

Comment: Copy the stacktrace and edit your question and paste it as code

Comment: I meant how to find out the stacktrace. I am deploying my web app using Netbeans on Apache Tomcat server.

Comment: When you run your program the on console you get some error describing the problem, just paste all that

Comment: I edited my previous comment.  I am deploying my web app using Netbeans on Apache Tomcat server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61510/discussion-between-sol4me-and-aaditya-bagga).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply cannot do this: the MySQL JDBC driver only supports TCP/IP and - on Windows - named pipes to connect to the database. Therefor specifying `--skip-networking` will not allow you to use JDBC MySQL Connector/J at all.

See also http://lists.mysql.com/java/8749:

> Java itself doesn't support unix domain sockets, but since you're on windows, you can use named pipes, [..]

The dead-link in the above post is now http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if named pipes can be used on Unix? The link in the post you referenced seems dead. Also could you recommend any other connector that does supoort Unix pipes.. I was trying to use the --skip-networking option for securtiy, perhaps using the --bind-address option to localhost and using a firewall to block all incoming connections serve as an alternative as I have read somewhere..

Comment: @AadityaBagga I have added the equivalent link in my answer. Namedpipes are - afaik - specifically for Windows, so you can't use it in Unix. Only binding on localhost or using a firewall is indeed a good option for securing the server.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. I also found a link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html, which lists some options for connecting. Marking as solved.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to use UNIX sockets with the Mysql JDBC Connector/J you need to provide a [*socketFactory*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

> `jdbc:mysql:///?user=test&password=test&socketFactory=<classname>&<socket>=/tmp/mysql.sock`

So this will vary with the implementation you use. By default, Mysql does not ship with any implementation for that, just provides an example for such a factory in it's source-code.

There is an existing UNIX socket Java library named [***junixsocket***](https://github.com/kohlschutter/junixsocket) which also has such a *socketFactory* class implementation. An example is outlined in [*Connecting to a MySQL database via Unix Domain Sockets*](https://code.google.com/p/junixsocket/wiki/ConnectingToMySQL) which is part of their documentation.

---

You can find more Java UNIX socket library alternatives in related Q&A material:

- [UNIX socket implementation for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/170600/367456)

Answer (score 10):

The JDBC Driver from the MariaDB project supports Unix domain sockets while remaining compatible with the MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver.  Example jdbc url for the MariaDB driver is: 
`jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/revmgt?localSocket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Worth noting that this requires including the JNA library as the MariaDB driver uses domain sockets via JNA internally.  I saw speed improvements for CPU bound java processes when using the unix domain sockets.  I believe this was largely from the offload of work from the java process to native code freeing up CPU cycles for the already CPU bottle necked java process.

Comment: In your connection string you mentioned the IP:port as localhost:3306. Does it require to mention the host properties while connecting via Unix Socket??

Comment: Seems including JNA library on classpath (jna-5.6.0.jar in my case) is absolutely critical. I've spent close to a day struggling to make mariadb connector work with consistent 'Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3306. Connection refused (Connection refused)'. In the same time, console-based mysql as well MySQLdb in Python worked fine. Simply including JNA on the classpath just made everything work. You do not have to specify '3306' on the url though. Sure enough, documentation for ConnectorJ does tell you to install JNA if you want to use sockets.

Answer (score 4):

As [another answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74858) pointed out, it's possible (at least in Intellij IDE) to use socket connection for [Mysql JDBC Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/) (I am using version 5.1) **without** having to provide a socketFactory,

> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: This really seemed useful, however I couldn't get it to work, and had to use junixsocket instead

Comment: @MatteoTassinari it's possible that Intellij IDE provides some extra libs to support the `socket` param approach.

Comment: The same works with Flyway. However, the [documentation still claims that they do not support it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-unix-socket.html). So there is probably some other library which adds support for this option in the background.

Comment: After some testing, I think what might actually happen is that we are using the MariaDB connector, since it is also listening to `jdbc:mysql:` and it is also on the classpath. If I use `&disableMariaDbDriver` as documented [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#having-mariadb-and-mysql-drivers-in-the-same-classpath), I run into problems.