# Accessing the host mysql from the docker Container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have tomcat WAR which I want to run inside a Docker having tomcat image. There is a **jdbc java Code**  in the war which access my ***local mysql*** from the docker container. But Docker is not able to connect to the local mysql.

I am able to run my war in tomcat locally. I have changed my `my.cnf` file bind-address to *.

`bind-address = *`

How can I configure my jdbc url so that it can connect to local mysql inside the Docker. After googling I came to know about the `docker.for.mac.host.internal` command map to host ip inside docker. I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: You can use `docker.for.mac.host.internal` in JDBC URL for the IP.

Comment: It is working fine and I am able to access host from the docker.

Answer (score 0):

You may connect using Unix Domain Socket by mounting:

```
volumes:
  -"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"
```

You will also need a compatible JDBC connector, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31891263/8622794